# How is "io.6,{9001JIAIua121698aa]]" too simplistic/systematic?

Tags: password

I just created a new user in CentOS 5.6 and run `passwd user`, providing the password `io.6,{9001JIAIua121698aa]]`. System says "BAD PASSWORD: it is too simplistic/systematic". Not a big deal (and it does accept it anyway), but I am really interested, how is this too simplistic/systematic?

Comment: My guess would be a check for repeated characters (`00 aa ]]`) that doesn't care how long the non-repeating parts of the password are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could only see a Apple [open source implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CrackLib/CrackLib-36064/cracklib27/cracklib/fascist.c), and it seems your password qualify as "too simplistic" in this case. The algorithms are likely to be similar.

The code is

```c
    #define MAXSTEP   4

    i = 0;
    ptr = password;
    while (ptr[0] && ptr[1])
    {
        if ((ptr[1] == (ptr[0] + 1)) || (ptr[1] == (ptr[0] - 1)))
        {
            i++;
        }
        ptr++;
    }

    if (i > MAXSTEP)
    {
        return ("it is too simplistic/systematic");
    }
```

Basically it takes all characters from the password, and checks if the next character is the current character +/- 1 (characters being one byte).

In the password you provided

```
  io.6,{9001JIAIua121698aa]]
```

`01`, `JI`, `12`, `21` and `98` increment the `i` counter. `MAXSTEP` being 4, the *it is too simplistic/systematic* message is triggered.

The algorithm is not very smart, as it does not take into account the length of the password, and the complexity of the other characters.